# How to store data on selenium hub?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid

I am executing the test scripts on selenium grid. Is it possible to save any data on selenium hub when executed in Jenkins?

Comment: You cannot save any data on the selenium hub atleast not with the plain vanilla selenium hub without you building customizations. Can you please elaborate on what you are after ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I want to save the screenshots if my tests failed so that debugging will be easy. That is the reason selenium hub or node was the best to do that...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the grid for that. You can make use of an EventFiringWebdriver wherein whenever there is an exception you can capture screenshots. Refer to [this](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2011/02/generating-screen-capture-on-exception.html) blog for more information.

Comment: The code dsnt say where the screenshot will be saving to be accessed later

Comment: @worrynerd  Once you have access to the screenshots as bytes, why don't you decide where to persist them ? Maybe on a shared file system (or) persist them as a BLOB object into a DB, you are free to decide where the data will be persisted.

Comment: I tried storing them on a shred drive but seems like the machine where the tests run don't have access to the shared drive that was the whole purpose of the question

Comment: Essentially there are 3 machines involved when you run tests against the Grid environment. Machine_A is where the tests are kicked off from [this is the machine wherein the screenshots will be available after they are retrieved from selenium using driver.takeScreenshot() method], Machine_B which represents the Hub and Machine_C which represents the node where the actual browser is invoked. So you are stating Machine_A doesn't have access to the shared drive ?  Please clarify